# Running ibm websphere like setup on Apache Tomcat or some open server

Tags: websphere

Is there a way to mimic IBM web sphere on an open appserver?  There are functions we use, ibm's jsecurity_check and their cookie ltpa token.  That should be it to get a functioning ibm like server.  Would those be available from an open server.  Even an open version of ibm websphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `j_security_check` is defined in the [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1335491608_a7948343220eec9b9beb6b85b6978c40), so any Java Web Container is compatible with that.

On the other side, LTPA token is an IBM Techology that's only used by IBM Products, so you need to find another way to implement single sign-on. As @Manglu said, that's more a Container concern that shouldn't have any impact in your application.

Some SSO solutions are described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173704/which-sso-framework-to-use

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by open version. If you are looking at free versions of WAS, you should look at WAS Developers edition

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/developer/

If your production is WAS then i would suggest you use this

***Deploy your applications with complete fidelity to a WAS production environment, rendering development to production migration a non-issue***

How are you using the LTPA token in  your application? This should typically be under the hood and you don't necessarily need to be using that in your application. I would be interested in hearing what you do with the LTPA token in your application!

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you're looking for something open, or something smaller. If you're already using WebSphere, but are looking for something smaller/lighter that still supports LTPA tokens, you might want to check out the new Liberty profile in WebSphere Application Server 8.5 (which was just announced). You can get the low-down and download versions to play with from http://wasdev.net

(disclaimer: I worked on it, I am biased)